# Django testing of neo4j database

Tags: django, neo4j, neomodel

I'm using django with neo4j as database and noemodel as OGM. How do I test it?

When I run `python3 manage.py test` all the changes, my tests make are left.

And also how do I make two databases, one for testing, another for working in production and specify which one to use how?

Comment: can you put your django's settings file, which package you used, i am struggling to connect neo4j with django, any resource to take a look at !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the reason all of your changes are being retained is due to using the same neo4j database for testing as you are using in development. Since neomodel isn't integrated tightly with Django it doesn't act the same way Django's ORM does when testing. Django will do some helpful things when you run tests using its ORM, such as creating a test database that will be destroyed upon completion.

With neo4j and neomodel I'd recommend doing the following:

### Create a Custom Test Runner

Django enables you to define a [custom test runner](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/advanced/#defining-a-test-runner) by setting the `TEST_RUNNER` settings variable. An extremely simple version of this to get you going would be:

```
from time import sleep
from subprocess import call

from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner


class MyTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def setup_databases(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Stop your development instance
        call("sudo service neo4j-service stop", shell=True)
        # Sleep to ensure the service has completely stopped
        sleep(1)
        # Start your test instance (see section below for more details)
        success = call("/path/to/test/db/neo4j-community-2.2.2/bin/neo4j"
                       " start-no-wait", shell=True)
        # Need to sleep to wait for the test instance to completely come up
        sleep(10)
        if success != 0:
            return False
        try:
            # For neo4j 2.2.x you'll need to set a password or deactivate auth
            # Nigel Small's py2neo gives us an easy way to accomplish this
            call("source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate && "
                 "/path/to/virtualenv/bin/neoauth "
                 "neo4j neo4j my-p4ssword")
        except OSError:
            pass
        # Don't import neomodel until we get here because we need to wait 
        # for the new db to be spawned
        from neomodel import db
        # Delete all previous entries in the db prior to running tests
        query = "match (n)-[r]-() delete n,r"
        db.cypher_query(query)
        super(MyTestRunner, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def teardown_databases(self, old_config, **kwargs):
        from neomodel import db
        # Delete all previous entries in the db after running tests
        query = "match (n)-[r]-() delete n,r"
        db.cypher_query(query)
        sleep(1)
        # Shut down test neo4j instance
        success = call("/path/to/test/db/neo4j-community-2.2.2/bin/neo4j"
                       " stop", shell=True)
        if success != 0:
            return False
        sleep(1)
        # start back up development instance
        call("sudo service neo4j-service start", shell=True)
```

### Add a secondary neo4j database

This can be done in a couple ways but to follow along with the test runner above you can download a community distribution from [neo4j's website](http://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/). With this secondary instance you can now swap between which database you'd like to use utilizing the command line statements used in the `call`s within the test runner.

## Wrap Up

This solution assume's you're on a linux box but should be portable to a different OS with minor modifications. Also I'd recommend checking out the [Django's Test Runner Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/advanced/#using-the-django-test-runner-to-test-reusable-applications) to expand upon what the test runner can do.

Answer (score 2):

There currently isn't mechanism for working with test databases in neomodel as neo4j only has 1 schema per instance.

However you can override the environment variable NEO4J_REST_URL when running the tests like so

export NEO4J_REST_URL=http://localhost:7473/db/data python3 manage.py test

Answer (score 0):

The way I went about this was to give in and use the existing database, but mark all test-related nodes and detach/delete them when finished.  It's obviously not ideal; all your node classes must inherit from `NodeBase` or risk polluting the db with test data, and if you have unique constraints, those will still be enforced across both live/test data.  But it works for my purposes, and I thought I'd share in case it helps someone else.

---

in `myproject/base.py`:

```py
from neomodel.properties import Property, validator
from django.conf import settings


class TestModeProperty(Property):
    """
    Boolean property that is only set during unit testing.
    """

    @validator
    def inflate(self, value):
        return bool(value)

    @validator
    def deflate(self, value):
        return bool(value)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.default = True
        self.has_default = settings.UNIT_TESTING


class NodeBase(StructuredNode):
    __abstract_node__ = True
    test_mode = TestModeProperty()
```

---

in `myproject/test_runner.py`:

```py
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner
from neomodel import db


class NeoDiscoverRunner(DiscoverRunner):

    def teardown_databases(self, old_config, **kwargs):
        db.cypher_query(
            """
            MATCH (node {test_mode: true})
            DETACH DELETE node
            """
        )
        return super().teardown_databases(old_config, **kwargs)
```

---

in `settings.py`:

```py
UNIT_TESTING = sys.argv[1:2] == ["test"]
TEST_RUNNER = "myproject.test_runner.NeoDiscoverRunner"
```